# A question on the Lagrange Inversion Formula

Tags: combinatorics, analytic-number-theory

I have to use the L.I.F. for

\begin{align*}
s\left(x,y\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-x-y-\sqrt{1-2x-2y-2xy+x^2+y^2}\right)
\end{align*}

to obtain that

\begin{align*}
s\left(x,y\right) = \sum_{p,q\geq1}\frac{1}{p+q-1}\binom{p+q-1}{p}\binom{p+q-1}{q}x^py^q
\end{align*}

I've tried finding some resources on examples on how to do this but so far I am quite clueless. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We seek to use Lagrange Inversion to show that

$$s(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}
\left(1-x-y-\sqrt{1-2x-2y-2xy+x^2+y^2}\right)$$

has the series expansion

$$\sum_{p,q\ge 1} \frac{1}{p+q-1}
{p+q-1\choose p} {p+q-1\choose q} x^p y^q.$$

On squaring we obtain

$$4 s(x,y)^2 = (1-x-y)^2 + 1-2x-2y-2xy+x^2+y^2
\\ - 2(1-x-y) (1-x-y-2s(x,y))
\\ = 2 (1-x-y)^2 - 4xy - 2(1-x-y) (1-x-y-2s(x,y))
\\ = - 4xy + 4 (1-x-y) s(x, y).$$

We finally get

$$s(x,y)^2 = -xy + (1-x-y) s(x,y).$$

This implies

$$x = \frac{s(x,y) (1 - y - s(x,y))}{y + s(x,y)}.$$

We get with $p\ge 1$

$$[x^p] s(x, y) = \frac{1}{p} [x^{p-1}] \frac{d}{dx} s(x, y)
= \frac{1}{p} \; \underset{x}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{1}{x^p} \frac{d}{dx} s(x,y).$$

Now put $s(x,y) = u$ so that $\frac{d}{dx} s(x, y) \; dx = du$

$$\frac{1}{p} \; \underset{u}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{(y+u)^p}{u^p (1-y-u)^p}
\\ = \frac{1}{p} \frac{1}{(1-y)^p} \; \underset{u}{\mathrm{res}} \;
\frac{(y+u)^p}{u^p (1-u/(1-y))^p}.$$

This is

$$\frac{1}{p} \frac{1}{(1-y)^p}
\sum_{r=0}^{p-1} {p\choose r} y^{p-r}
{2p-2-r\choose p-1} \frac{1}{(1-y)^{p-1-r}}.$$

Extracting the coefficient on $[y^q]$ where we see that $q\ge 1$:

$$\frac{1}{p}
\sum_{r=0}^{p-1} {p\choose r} [y^q] y^{p-r}
{2p-2-r\choose p-1} \frac{1}{(1-y)^{2p-1-r}}
\\ = \frac{1}{p}
\sum_{r=0}^{p-1} {p\choose r}
{2p-2-r\choose p-1} {q+p-2\choose 2p-2-r}.$$

Next observe that

$${2p-2-r\choose p-1} {q+p-2\choose 2p-2-r}
= \frac{(q+p-2)!}{(p-1)! \times (p-1-r)! \times (q+r-p)!}
\\ = {p+q-2\choose p-1} {q-1\choose p-1-r}.$$

We get for our sum

$$\frac{1}{p} {p+q-2\choose p-1}
\sum_{r=0}^{p-1} {p\choose r} {q-1\choose p-1-r}
\\ = \frac{1}{p} {p+q-2\choose p-1} {p+q-1\choose p-1}.$$

This was Vandermonde. Some binomial coefficient algebra now yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{p+q-1} {p+q-1\choose p} {p+q-1\choose q}}$$

as claimed.

This  was from Egorychev's *Combinatorial sums*.

Comment: Hi Marko, first off, thank you so much for your very thorough and detailed answer. I sincerely appreciate all the effort and time you spent in doing this. It's part of a paper I am reading by Bousquet Melou - Exactly Solved Models of Polyominoes and Polygons - (http://fr.arxiv.org/abs/0811.4415 here is arxiv link). The equation that I am actually trying to perform the Lagrange Inversion on is $S(x,y)=xS(x,y) + xy + yS(x,y) + S^2(x,y)$, or more simply put, $S = xS + xy + yS + S^2$, (I used a version solved by quad. formula) is there maybe some substitution that could give $S = \alpha \phi(S)$?

Comment: I am trying to put the equation in the form found in $\textit{Wilf's Generating Functionology}$

Comment: Do you perhaps have any examples where L.I.F. as in $\textit{Wilf}$ is used for equations in 2 variables?

Comment: Using the substitution $u=xy$ and $v=x+y$ and treating $v$ as a parameter should let you solve for $u$ and then apply LIF (I did this step manually but you may also apply LIF directly). This should produce the series in $u$ and $v$ that I have above. Furthermore it may turn out to be easier to treat $y$ as a parameter and use the univariate LIF with $x.$

Comment: @Pablo I will look into this but I cannot promise anything.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Great derivation! (+1)

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there is a better proof using multivariate LIF. The symmetry in the answer is very suggestive, my proof is not symmetric.